# How to get this kind of subset from a DataFrame in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, I have the following DataFrame

```
+-----+----+------+
| idx | id | type |
+-----+----+------+
|   0 | 10 | a    |
|   1 | 10 | b    |
|   2 | 20 | b    |
|   3 | 30 | a    |
+-----+----+------+
```

I want such a subset via following sequential steps:

1. get all the `id` of the `type` **a**

   - the filtered `id` are **10** and **30**
2. get all the rows where the `id` are the same as above

   - the rows `0`, `1` and `3` are selected

The resulting subset DataFrame is:

```
+-----+----+------+
| idx | id | type |
+-----+----+------+
|   0 | 10 | a    |
|   1 | 10 | b    |
|   3 | 30 | a    |
+-----+----+------+
```

How can I implement this in `pyspark`? Thanks in advance.

---

Another follow up question, how to implement the following.

If the step is changed to:

2. get all the rows where the `id` are **different** than above

   - the rows `2` is selected, because only this row's `id` is not **10** or **30**

The resulting DataFrame should be:

```
+-----+----+------+
| idx | id | type |
+-----+----+------+
|   2 | 20 | b    |
+-----+----+------+
```

Comment: Use a self join - off the top of my head something like `df.alias('r').join(df.alias('l').where("l.type = 'a'").select('id'), on="id", how="inner").show()` should get you pretty close

Comment: thanks for your answer @pault

Comment: @pault hi, could you also help me with the second question? Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter and join operation.
1.

```
filterDF = dataDF.filter(dataDF.type == "a")
joinedDS = dataDF.join(filterDF, on="id")
```

For point number 2 you can use left_anti join

```
joinedDS1 =  dataDF.join(joinedDS, on="id", how='left_anti')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, another follow up question: for step 2, how can I get the rows excluding the `id` filtered? so the result should row 2 is selected because only row 2 has the `id`, which is not `10` or `30`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your answer, there is one problem, that the columns after joining are duplicated. How can I avoid duplicating the columns when joining?

Comment: you can use drop column option

Comment: Thanks, your solution solves the particular question. But my Dataframe has multiple columns, when joining, all the columns are duplicated. I tried `drop(dataDF.columns)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @TrW236  You can then specify the selected columns

Comment: I have more than 10 columns, is there a simple method to remove all the duplicates once at a time?

Comment: there is no straight way as per I know. You need to write a small program for that. Please check https://thispointer.com/how-to-find-drop-duplicate-columns-in-a-dataframe-python-pandas/

Comment: @dassum I can think of 2 simple ways. 1) `filterDF = dataDF.filter(dataDF.type == "a").select("id")` or 2) Use alias like in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732146/how-to-get-this-kind-of-subset-from-a-dataframe-in-pyspark#comment103755178_58732146) and add `select("r.*")`